# Algorithm for determining factorability

Tags: probability-or-statistics, polynomials, algorithm

Consider the following polynomial :

$P[x,y]:=a_{11}+a_{12}y+a_{13}y^2+a_{21}x+a_{22}x y+a_{23}x y^2+a_{31}x^2+a_{32}x^2 y+a_{33}x^2 y^2$

where the $a_{ij}$ are either $1$ or $-1$. Thus there are $2^9=512$ possible polynomials. I want to find out of these 512, how many are factorable (or alternatively how many are irreducible). Instead of going through each case of coefficients, is there an algorithm or some way to do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Why not just go through each of the 512 polynomials and test Factor on each?  Why is such a solution unacceptable to you?

Comment: I guess I could, however I'd also like to consider polynomials of higher degree with more coefficients so there will be much more to test factor. For example, the next polynomial Id like to test will have 16 coefficients so $2^{16}=65,536$ possible polynomials. I'm not sure If I could test each one in a normal timespan.

Comment: @David_Shmij Agreed, testing all those polynomials would be time-prohibitive at the speed of the code shown in my answer below (it would take approximately 2 years, for serial code, probably a bit better with parallelization). However, I think your problem becomes a mathematical one then, rather than one concerning *Mathematica* per se...

Comment: Indeed, I will look into the mathematical side of this. Thanks for the detailed and perfect help with the case of 9 coefficients!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of polynomials is not so great in your original case: just generate them all programmatically, and test each one for irreducibility using [`IrreduciblePolynomialQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IrreduciblePolynomialQ.html), which seems faster than actually doing the factorization using `Factor`:

```
p[x_, y_] = Total[Table[a[i, j] x^(i - 1) y^(j - 1), {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}], 2];
polynomials = p[x, y] /. Thread[Flatten[Array[a, {3, 3}]] -> #] & /@ Tuples[{1, -1}, {9}];

# -> IrreduciblePolynomialQ[#] & /@ polynomials

(* Out:

{1 + x + x^2 + y + x y + x^2 y + y^2 + x y^2 + x^2 y^2 -> False, 
 1 + x + x^2 + y + x y + x^2 y + y^2 + x y^2 - x^2 y^2 -> True, 
 1 + x + x^2 + y + x y - x^2 y + y^2 + x y^2 + x^2 y^2 -> True, 
 1 + x + x^2 + y + x y - x^2 y + y^2 + x y^2 - x^2 y^2 -> True, 
 1 + x - x^2 + y + x y + x^2 y + y^2 + x y^2 + x^2 y^2 -> True, 
 ...
}
*)
```

The process is relatively fast with this relatively small number of expression:

```
# -> IrreduciblePolynomialQ[#] & /@ polynomials; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {0.383, Null} *)
```

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind.  (+1).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you! I estimated the time it would take to scale this to the size of the larger problem he mentioned, however, and it becomes prohibitive. I don't know of a faster brute-force approach (barring significant gains using parallelization).

Comment: You can certainly eliminate half the polynomials from consideration (because they are related by a factor of -1 to others tested).  And when I parallelize the question as asked, it takes 0.133 seconds on a 8-core Mac.